# Ubuntu 10.4 Lucid Server Minimal Install: Slow terminal scrolling

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have a minimal install of Ubuntu 10.4 Server for testing and learning purposes. There is a very annoying occurrance: whenever I try to "man dpkg" or any command that load a few screens length of text (eg. "ls -al") the redraw speed of the console is just way too slow. I can see how each new line causes the whole screen to redraw.

Note: that this doesn't happen inside X. No gui is installed. I have been experimenting with adding vesafb to the grub line as some guides suggested, but no speedups happened.

You might be able to reproduce this behaviour on your linux system by switching to terminal using CTRL+ALT+F1.

Is there any way to speed scrolling up?

Comment: +1 : It is really annoying to have such a slow console on a modern computer ... Did the framebuffer off trick solved it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try [disabling the frame buffer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer#How%20to%20disable%20the%20framebuffer) altogether. While it looks much nicer than regular VGA text mode, it's almost always a lot slower, especially at high resolutions. The link provided goes to the Ubuntu Wiki page describing how to do it.

Comment: +1: I will try it ... Anyway it's strange that it is so slow on modern computer ...